# Missing "types" property of @google-vision npm package

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

When trying to use the "types" enum of the google-vision package an error is thrown, and no such property exists in the object.

The documentation on how to use is here:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#methods

This is the code and error. You can see in the variables section on the left there is no "types" property to the object.
[image: My code and error]

The documentation it states i should access the types of fearture like this:

```
[{type: vision.types.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION},
    {type: vision.types.Feature.Type.WEB_DETECTION}]
```

I believe this is what I have done.

I would appreciate any comments on what the problem may be.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The [nodejs sample code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch) uses strings instead of enums. Can you try using a string instead?